# nth root of non diagonalizable matrix

Tags: matrices, jordan-normal-form

Good day,

I am interest in math, and while doing the exercise. I can find the nth root of the matrix if it is diagonalizable, using the $A^n = P*Q*P^-$, where Q is the diagonal, and P are the eigenvectors.
But I found that it is not possible if matrix is not diagonalizable. For example what if I have 2 same eigen vectors and A is 2x2 matrix. So it is not possible to solve it. I have found the matrix for this case:
\begin{bmatrix}
8 & 1\\
-4 & 12 
\end{bmatrix}

What if i want to find the 19th root of this matrix. I found the eigen values(10) and vectors(0.5 1). How to solve this kind of problems?

Comment: See [Analytic function of a matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_function_of_a_matrix), and also [this excellent book](https://archive.siam.org/books/ot104/) by Nick Higham. The first chapter is available for free, and mentions [Lagrange-Hermite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite_interpolation) interpolation on the spectrum of the matrix, as well as a method using the Jordan normal form, among others.

Comment: Thanks for the books, i read about the Jordan decomposition, still could not solve it for the given situation. Can you give more explanantion?

Comment: If you know what powers of, say, $A=\pmatrix{1&1\cr0&1\cr}$ look like, then you should be able to find, say, a 19th root of $A$. Similarly for other matrices in Jordan form.

Comment: See also [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_matrix#Functions_of_matrices) which explains why the function of a Jordan block has a finite power series. And also note that $A=QJQ^{-1}$ with $J=\begin{bmatrix}10 & 1 \\ 0 & 10\end{bmatrix}$and $Q=\begin{bmatrix}-2 & 1 \\ -4 & 0\end{bmatrix}$. There is not much more to do, except finding the derivative of $x^{1/19}$.

Comment: Problem is the same with Jordan form as well, A = $\big(\begin{smallmatrix}
  8 & 1\\
  -4 & 12
\end{smallmatrix}\big)$  and I have only 1 eigenvector, and I can not solve it with the Jordan form

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut how did you find the Q? Should it be $\big(\begin{smallmatrix}
  0.5 & 0.5\\
  1 & 1
\end{smallmatrix}\big)$ ?

Comment: The links I gave show you every step. Of course you have only one eigenvector, otherwise the matrix would be diagonalizable. It's the point of having a Jordan form. And your $Q$ is singular... You are confusing eigendecomposition and Jordan form.

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1570526/computing-the-jordan-form-of-a-matrix for finding Q.

Comment: As far as I understood, the reason of taking $\big(\begin{smallmatrix}
  -2 \\
  -4
\end{smallmatrix}\big)$ because, it will make easy to find the 2nd one, which is the [1,0]?

Comment: Thanks a lot, so using $\big(\begin{smallmatrix}
  0.5 & -1/4\\
  1 &  0
\end{smallmatrix}\big)$  would also result to the same asnwer. Thanks a lot for spending time on it